# How to select only label from a dict for graph title (Plotly Dash)

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly-dash

I have a dictionary with labels and key as shown below.

```
country = pd.read_csv('assets/countries.csv')
country = country.set_index('Code')
country_options = [{'label': f'({cod}) {country.loc[cod, "Country"]} ',
                  'value': f'{cod}'} for cod in country.index]
```

[{'label': '(AFG) Afghanistan ', 'value': 'AFG'}, {'label': '(ALB) Albania ', 'value': 'ALB'}, {'label': '(DZA) Algeria '.....

I also have a callback to update a graph and would like to add the title depending on the option selected from a dropdown list.

```
def update_graph(indi=indicator_options,coun=country_options):
df = indicator_select(coun, indi)
graph_content = dict(data=line_plot(df),
                    layout=go.Layout(
                        title=coun,
                        yaxis=dict(hoverformat='.1f'),
                        )
                    )
return graph_content
```

However, the title=coun will return me the 3 letter symbol (value) of the dict, but I need the label with the symbol and the name. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` prop of the dropdown will only ever return the `value` part of the `options` dictionary, and not the `label` part. What you could do is create a mapping for the values you need, like this:

```py
country_labels = [{f'{cod}': f'({cod}) {country.loc[cod, "Country"]}'} for cod in country.index]
```

And then just do `title=country_labels[coun],`